# difference between joining with WHERE AND JOIN in SELECT clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two queries:

```
select id,(SELECT N.NAME
        FROM memuat.NETWORK N 
        join memuat.host H
        on N.ID = H.NETWORK ) as network_name
from memuat.host;
        
select id,(SELECT N.NAME
        FROM memuat.NETWORK N
        where N.ID = H.NETWORK ) as network_name
from memuat.host H;
```

The first returns:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

the second runs fine and returns data. It is clear to me that the first returns more than one row , because I can run the sub-query alone and check that. What it's not clear to me is how the second query can return only one row ? My result is not a single row, it's multiple rows.

Comment: The second query has a _correlated subquery_. I.e. it has a condition referencing the main query table H.

Comment: ok, but what that do ? it returns one row ?

Comment: For each row selected from H, the subquery is executed. And the N.ID = H.NETWORK condition in the subqeury is evaluated.

Comment: but that would only work if `N.ID` is a unique index right ?

Comment: If there are two (or more) rows in N fulfilling the condition, you'll get the "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" error.

Comment: ... And in that case the column should not be called ID, as a table's ID is supposed to uniquely identify a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both queries, the subquery gets executed once per host row.

In your second query the subquery is:

```
select n.name from memuat.network n where n.id = h.network
```

This gets the network name for the host's network ID.

In your first query the subquery is:

```
SELECT n.name
FROM memuat.network n 
JOIN memuat.host h ON n.id = h.network
```

This gets list of network names. Probably with many duplicates, because we get one row per host.

The main query in both cases is:

```
SELECT id, ( <subquery> ) AS network_name
FROM memuat.host h;
```

Here the subquery is supposed to return one value, namely the host's network name. As the subquery in your second query returns one row with one value, this works. As the subquery in your first query returns many rows, you get an error.

Comment: ok, got it. so it's not about using `where` or `join` but rather to reference the outer query in the inner or not ? or is it only possible to build a query that references the outer query with the `where` statement in this case ? I tried to reference the outer query with `join` but did not manage.

Comment: In the second query the inner query has a reference to the row in the main query (`h.network`). This is called a correlated subquery. In the first query, there is no such reference. It is a stand-alone subquery, also called non-correlated subquery. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I would like to actually know if I can change the first query so as to achieve the same thing as the second query, but keeping the `join` keyword in the statement. is that possible to do ?

Comment: Yes, it just wouldn't make sense, though. The subquery gets too many rows, because it is selecting network names for all hosts instead of the one host in the main query. With `where host.id = h.id` you would select the same one host row in the subquery that you already have in the main query (provided that table has a unique ID). You can even use the row's address for this: ``where host.rowid = h.rowid``.